# upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers EnvoyProxy

Tags: envoyproxy

It seems that the source IP changes after going through envoy. After reading this:
https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/listeners/listener_filters/original_src_filter#example-listener-configuration
I tried adding the below to the listener at port 80 no connection could be made on that port.

```
listener_filters:
  - name: envoy.filters.listener.original_src
  typed_config:
  "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.listener.original_src.v3.OriginalSrc
  mark: 123
```

The Error I got after hitting any endpoint on that listener:
`upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure`

How to prevent envoy from changing the source ip and why did I get this error?

Comment: Please provide your full Envoy config.  There's not enough information here to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your cluster timeout and try again. (it's in the definition of the cluster  **"connect_timeout"** )